# Default value c# function but not the last

Tags: c#

Say I have a function

```
void func (int a = 0, int b = 1)
{
     //do something
}
```

and I want to give b a value, but not a

```
func( , 10);
```

I cannot change the func function, because I have not created it, is there a keyword to say: use default value for this parameter?

Comment: Just specify `b` in the call to the function: `func(b:10);`

Comment: You can't have a semicolon inside the parameter list.

Comment: @Amy: I think it's reasonable to assume that's just a typo, and that the actual method declaration is something like `void Func(int a = 0, int b = 1)`. While it would be nice to see actual code instead of pseudo-code, I think the question can still be answered before the OP confirms that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of explicitly saying "use the default value for this argument", but instead you can avoid specifying any arguments where you *don't* want the default value. When you want to omit an argument but specify a later one, you have to use [*named arguments*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) - basically just specifying the name of the parameter that the argument is meant to correspond to. In your case, you want to provide an argument for the `b` parameter, so you call it like this:

```
Func(b: 10);
```

If you only wanted to supply an argument for the `a` parameter, you could either use a named argument for clarity:

```
Func(a: 10);
```

or just use a positional argument:

```
Func(10); // The compiler assumes this corresponds to the first parameter
```